# Whats the best method to to filter graph edges by type in AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have the following super-simple graph : [image: picture of graph]

What i am trying to do is:

1. Select all questions where there is a property on the question document called firstQuestion with a value of true.
2. Select any options that are connected to the question via an outbound edge of type with_options

The following query works, however it feels like there must be a better way to inspect the edge type without using string operations - specifically the concatenation operation i use to recreate the edge _id value by joining it to the key with the edge type i want - **is this the best way to inspect the type of edge?**

```
FOR question IN questions 
FILTER question.firstQuestion == true
    let options = 
        (FOR v, e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND question._id GRAPH 'mygraph'
        FILTER CONCAT('with_options/', e._key) == e._id
        RETURN v)
RETURN {question: question, options: options}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're currently introducing [IS_SAME_COLLECTION](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/2.8/CHANGELOG) for that specific purpose with ArangoDB 2.8.1.
The [DOCUMENT](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/MiscellaneousFunctions.html#miscellaneous_functions) function is also worth to mention in this context.

```
FOR question IN questions 
  FILTER question.firstQuestion == true
  LET options = (FOR v, e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND question._id GRAPH 'mygraph'
                   FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('with_options', e._id)
                     RETURN v)
  RETURN {question: question, options: options}
```

However, the best solution in this special case is not to use the named graph interface, but [specify the list of edge collections that should be concerned by the traversal](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html#working_on_collection_sets:) in first place:

```
FOR question IN questions 
  FILTER question.firstQuestion == true
  LET options = (FOR v, e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND question._id with_options RETURN v)
  RETURN {question: question, options: options}
```