# ArangoDB: filter by collection type in a traversal query

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am using ArangoDB 2.8

I am doing a traversal query that includes 2 different collections. However in my result I would like to get only a particular collection, but I don't see the way to filter by collection name.

In my case I have `address` collection and `user` collection. In `address` collection I distinguish 3 levels as: {addressType: state}, {addressType: city} and {addressType: street}. Then I have an edge that links from `address` to `user` collection (state>city>street>user). I want to do a traversal (like in the code below) from an `address` (of any type) to the `user` (if any) and only return the collection of type `user` -for example if a street does not have a link to a user then return empty-.

```
For p in TRAVERSAL(address, myEdge, @vertex_id, 'outbound', {paths:false})
   RETURN p.vertex._id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another answer is using the `IS_SAME_COLLECTION` function as hinted by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083929/195651):

```
FOR p IN TRAVERSAL(address, myEdge, @vertex_id, 'outbound', {paths:false})
  FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('user', p.vertex._id)
   RETURN p.vertex._id)
```

or, since `TRAVERSAL` was removed in ArangoDB 3.0+ ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455096/195651) and the [migration guide](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/cookbook/AQL/MigratingEdgeFunctionsTo3.html)), something like

```
FOR v IN 0..5 IN OUTBOUND @vertex_id myEdge
  FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('user', v._id)
   RETURN v._id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I had to find a solution, so here is mine (I know is not the best but worked for me):

What I do is split the `_id` by `"/"` and check whether the first part (collection name) is in `['user']`

```
For p in TRAVERSAL(address, myEdge, @vertex_id, 'outbound', {paths:false})
  FILTER (SPLIT(p.vertex._id, "/", 1)[0]) IN ['user']
   RETURN p.vertex._id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OPTIONS:

```
WITH users
FOR v IN 0..5 IN OUTBOUND @vertex_id myEdge
  OPTIONS {vertexCollections: ['users']}
   RETURN v._id
```

Take a look here https://docs.arangodb.com/3.12/aql/graphs/traversals/